# Вывод даты и времени

Tags: php, sql

Есть код, который должен выводить дату и время в формате **yy.mm.dd hh:mm**. Так вот чем отличается **mm** (месяц) от **mm** (минуты)? - Ничем.
Собственно, вопрос: как вывести именно месяц и минуты?

```
date("d.m.y в h:m", strtotime($news[$i]["date"]))
```

Смотрел различные статьи, но нигде ничего не нашел (да, может хренова ищу). Единственное решение из поиска, которое могло бы подойти - это частичный вывод, например, day("переменная"), month("переменная") и т.д., но это решение для вывода с SQL, а мне же нужно в PHP.

Comment: Как не отличаются. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php найдите строку "минуты" в таблице. там буква `i`

Comment: Вот, что значит сделать один раз. Забыл совсем, что формат вывода времени не h:m:s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date("m в i", strtotime($news[$i]["date"]));
```